# Aura doc support attribute for lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

Probably very silly.
I'm looking at aura doc page of my custom components and I can't figure out where to place the "support" attribute [the reference page mentiones](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference) to change the status of my components to GA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not supported at the moment in Lightning Components doc.